# display data from wcf service on mvc3 razor client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, razor

I have a client asp.net mvc3 razoc which consumes a wcf service.
I have a method GetTopCollections which return Collection[] "Top collections on the server"
and I have a method GetTreeView(string id) which return only the first level of this Collection not all the tree.

I want, on the first time to display top collections(It's done), And when I click on the one of those top collections, I display the first level of it's tree by calling the method GetTreeView(handle).

This is the first method on the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        client = new DSServiceClient();
        Collection[] _top = new Collection[10];
        client.Open();
        _top = client.GetTopCollections();
        client.Close();
        return View(_top);
    }
```

this is the view of GetData

```
@model DSClient.Controllers.Collection[]

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "GetData";
   @Html.ActionLink( @Model.ElementAt(0).Handle,"GetData3","Home",new { handle=@Model.ElementAt(0).Handle });
 }
```

this is GetData2()

```
public PartialViewResult GetData2(string handle)
    {
        client = new DSServiceClient();
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        tree = client.GetTreeView(handle);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/GetData2.cshtml",tree);
    }
```

And this is the view of GetData2

```
@model DSClient.Controllers.Tree

@{
ViewBag.Title = "GetData3";
@Model.listObjects.ElementAt(0).Name;
}
```

And this is the link to call the GetData

```
@Html.ActionLink("WebService", "GetData", "Home")
```

My problem is that the result of GetData3 is displayed on on other view, but I want to display that on the same view.Like a Tree View.
Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either:

1. Render the whole tree and hide the second level until the user clicks it
2. Load only the first level like you are doing and use AJAX to load the others as the user clicks them

Some jQuery tree views for you -> http://freebiesdesign.com/7-best-jquery-treeview-plugins/

Comment: Ok, I will try the second solution with ajax.